# Saving a Javascript Variable in a new file

Tags: php, javascript

I have a Javascript variable that is an object with keys and arrays (shortened version shown below). I scripted in HTML a form so that a users with access (after they login) can delete, add, or alter any of the Keys for their genealogy. What I need to know is how to take this new, altered variable and save it to the server as say, userNameGenealogy.js so that another page can use it. I have done some searching, but do not know if what I need is only PHP oriented, or if I will need to look into AJAX or JSON as well.

```
var genealogy = {};
    genealogy["Johnson"] = {
        "Ron": new Array(
            {"nickname":"Ronny","dob":"06/20/88"},
            {"nickname":"Ronald","dob":"03/15/54"}),
        "Scott": new Array(
            {"nickname":"Scotty","dob":"01/21/42"})
    };
```

This is just a short snippet, but I'd prefer not to have to change the format of the Javascript, as the rest of the site is coded to work with it as is. Any help / point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you retrieving things from the server?

Comment: It's a separate javascript file that is called on page load using script src

Comment: So you storing data in a '.js' file and then retrieving it as src? That's not a good way to do it. Essentially you should have a front end and a back end and pass data between the two using either normal send and receive or create a backend api and use ajax at the front end to exchange data.

Comment: I presume the backend would be storing the javascript variable in a database, and having the site call it when needed? If so, would you mind pointing me in the direction of what combination of languages would be easiest to learn for storing, saving, and passing the info? I presume PHP and mySQL?

Comment: Yes indeed. There's a whole host of options for you to choose from, and your decision should be based on a number of factor; previous / current experience... I went for  php/mysql... although if you know javascript, you could try node.js; it's gaining in popularity and you don't have to learn a whole new set of syntax; there's also Ruby on Rails, Python, .NET etc... If you went for PHP then I suggest using a framework like Laravel... Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax for that. For example with [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#example-0) and pass `data` parameter to it. Then you need to handle that in PHP script in which you have to read $_POST (in case below) parse it as you like it, save to file and echo response.

JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Comment: That would seem to just pass the object's literals to the PHP function that I would create. The users will be able to delete the whole "Ron" or "Scott" arrays and so forth. Is it possible to send anything beyond key/value pairs?

Comment: You can send whatever you like: objects, arrays, strings, integers, etc. Its up to your requirements how you will format the data and what way would be the most efficient.

Comment: So it would be possible to pass along the variable genealogy, and it will include all keys/arrays etc, or will I need to use loops to pass everything through?

Comment: Yes, you can pass your whole `genealogy` object, and when you will access it in php it will be associative array.